# Is there a name for this pattern, representing one-to-many relationships by adding columns with an index to a single table?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, database-theory

So a domain expert wants the following relation:

```
CarOwners(owner_id, name, address, car_1_registration, car_2_registration, car_3_registration, car_4_registration)
```

The reason given that most people are unlikely to have more cars than that, and that it's easier to reason with than the general case of an arbitrary number of cars. This seems like a common pattern for Excel jockeys, whereas for a DBA it would be much easier to simply have a separate relation:

```
Car(registration, owner_id)
```

But this idea is hard to sell to anyone who doesn't know what a JOIN is.

I looked in database literature and couldn't find any references to this (arguably anti-)pattern. Perhaps there's nothing theoretically wrong with it (it's just impractical), or it's simply too goofy to even be considered by academics. But it would be interesting to hear if it's actually covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(it's just impractical)

Interesting, the purpose might be served. Smart Technology for the Smart people. Database comes to play in his roles due to overcome these issue.

The main problem with this is, it's not extensible If 'car_5_registration' comes on the floor.

Comment: That answer seems plausible. It probably wouldn't occur to anyone who's actually into database theory to go to extra lengths for a worse schema. But I don't quite understand what you mean by the second paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

The Domain Expert has given you a requirement disguised as an implementation detail. I would implement this by:

- Implementing a relation table as you want
- Implementing a view which will give up to 4 associated registrations per owner

When an owner registers a fifth registration the system should keep working with no problem (which is probably what the DE wants) but the view he uses for reporting will still only show 4 registrations. (Maybe the view could include the total number of registrations per owner as well?)

This way you may have to change the view (used only for reporting) every now and then, rather than have to change a major table and all the relations and code that will be affected.

Comment: +1 for adroitly giving the DE whatt the DE needs.

Comment: The advice is absolutely correct, but it's not an answer to the question, I'm afraid.

Comment: @SalvatoreShiggerino - fair enough. Incidentally, implementing the relation table as you wanted is called 'Third Normal Form', and all RdBMS's should have their data in 3NF. Not having data in 3NF (as the DE requested) is called 'un-normalised' and has all sorts of (usually dire) consequences.

Comment: With the assumption that every man has four cars numbered 1 through 4, I don't see a clear conflict with 3NF. On the other hand I can see it conforming to the letter but not the spirit of the law for 1NF in that you can't have something like a comma-separated list of car license plate numbers in one of your columns. The only real advantage of using separate columns is that you no longer have to call `SPLIT_PART()` to get a specific car, but your queries will still be a mess, and adding more cars will be an even bigger mess.